# 'USB_Close': identifier not found... 'len': undeclared identifier...

Tags: visual-studio

I wrote a code that accesses LEDs on an FPGA. Anyway, I cannot successfully compile the following code in Visual Studio:

```
#ifdef STATS_LIBRARY_EXPORTS
#    define LIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#    define LIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <bitset>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "C:\Cypress\Cypress Suite USB 3.4.7\CyAPI\inc\CyAPI.h"





_declspec(dllexport) int excite_LED(bool start, int on) {


int i;
USB_Open();
for(i=0; i<100; i++) // blink the LEDs for a few seconds
{
USB_BulkWrite(2, &i, 1); // send one single byte (= the value of i) to FIFO2
Sleep(50); // and wait 50ms


BulkOutPipe2->XferData((PUCHAR)&i, len);    // send one byte (the value of i) to FIFO2


//Send command to FPGA
//status = !BulkOutPipe2->XferData(fpgaCommunicator, fpgaCommunicatorBytes);


}
USB_Close();

}
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
left of '->XferData' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
identifier "USB_Open" is undefined  
identifier "USB_Close" is undefined
identifier "USB_BulkWrite" is undefined
identifier "len" is undefined
identifier "BulkOutPipe2" is undefined
cannot open source file "stdafx.h"
'USB_Open': identifier not found
'USB_Close': identifier not found
'USB_BulkWrite': identifier not found
'len': undeclared identifier
'BulkOutPipe2': undeclared identifier
```

How can I fix my code to get rid of these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BulkOutPipe2 is a common define for EndPoint 3 in many samples, but its not set in CyAPI.h, so you need to set it yourself:

```
#define BulkOutPipe2 USBDevice->EndPoints[3]
```

Which you need to initialise:
    CCyUSBDevice *USBDevice = new CCyUSBDevice(NULL, ...);

Len is also not defined:

```
LONG len= 512000;
```

USB_BulkWrite (and other USB_) looks like usb_bulk_write, which is part of the libusb api. But you are trying to use with the CyApi (which is a lot different), so remove those method calls.

Comment: Thank you for your help! How do I determine the second parameter for newCCYUSBDevice(NULL, ...)?

Comment: According to the documentation, the second parameter defines the device with the id you want. If you only have one, you can leave it and just CCyUSBDevice(NULL).